# Form multiple inputs to PHP Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

I'm a new with PHP Array and have a form that input multiple parent-child data and save into an array. HTML will be something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="text" name="group[0][name]" placeholder="Group name">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>Member #1</p>
        <input type="text" name="group[0][member][0][name]" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" name="group[0][member][0][age]" placeholder="Age">
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Member #2</p>
        <input type="text" name="group[0][member][1][name]" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" name="group[0][member][1][age]" placeholder="Age">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input type="text" name="group[1][name]" placeholder="Group name">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>Member #1</p>
        <input type="text" name="group[1][member][0][name]" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" name="group[1][member][0][age]" placeholder="Age">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

PHP code:

```
$output = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ( $_POST['group'] as $group ) {
    $members = array();
    $m = 0;
    foreach ( $_POST['group'][$i]['member'] as $name ) {
        $members[$i][] = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'age' => $_POST['group'][$i]['member'][$m]
        );
        $m++;
    }
    $output[] = array(
        'group_name' => $_POST['group'][$i]['name'],
        'members' => $members[$i]
    );
    $i++;
}
var_dump( $output );
```

And I got this result:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'group_name' => string 'Group 1' (length=7)
      'members' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'group_name' => string 'Group 2' (length=7)
      'members' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
```

Can't get the member names and ages to be submitted into array. Can somebody help me? And sorry if I didn't explain this correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Start by showing yourself the complete array being sent to you by doing a `print_r($_POST)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to process down the heirarchy, using the new arrays created by the foreach loop is also easier to understand than going back to the master array like you woudl have to in a `for` loop

```
$output = [];

foreach ( $_POST['group'] as $group ) {
    $mem = [];  // init the members each time you start a new group
    foreach ( $group['member'] as $member) {
        $mem[] = ['name' => $member['name'], 'age' => $member['age']];
    }

    $output[] = [ 'group_name' => $group, 'members' => $mem ];
}
```